# BigQuery - Regex to match a pattern after a known string (positive lookbehind alternative)

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, regex-lookarounds, re2

I need to extract 8 digits after a known string:

```
| MyString                     | Extract: | 
| ---------------------------- | -------- | 
| mypasswordis 12345678        | 12345678 | 
| # mypasswordis 12345678      | 12345678 | 
| foobar mypasswordis 12345678 | 12345678 |
```

I can do this with regex like:

```
(?<=mypasswordis.*)[0-9]{8})
```

However, when I want to do this in BigQuery using the [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract) command, I get the error message, "Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?<".

I searched through the [re2 library](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) and saw there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for positive lookbehind.

Is there any way I can do this using other methods? Something like

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(MyString, r"(?<=mypasswordis.*)[0-9]{8}"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a capturing group here to extract a part of a pattern, see the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT` docs you linked to](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract):

> **If the regular expression contains a capturing group, the function returns the substring that is matched by that capturing group.** If the expression does not contain a capturing group, the function returns the entire matching substring.

Also, the `.*` pattern is too costly, you only need to match whitespace between the word and the digits.

**In general**, to "convert" a `(?<=mypasswordis).*` pattern with a positive lookbehind, you can use `mypasswordis(.*)`.

In this case, you can use

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(MyString, r"mypasswordis\s*([0-9]{8})"))
```

Or just

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(MyString, r"mypasswordis\s*([0-9]+)"))
```

See the [re2 regex online test](https://regex101.com/r/zMQN1s/1).

Comment: According to [re2 documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax#perl), you can also use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. This makes it `(\d{8})` or `(\d+)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to not use regexp as much as you can, its quite slow. Try substring and instr as example:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(MyString, INSTR(MyString,'mypasswordis') + LENGTH('mypasswordis')+1)
```

otherwise Wiktor Stribiżew have probably right answer.

Comment: Regex is "slow" but helps to get precise values, only those that are necessary and from the specified context. The regex is better when the input string format is not fixed. Say, the number of whitespace chars between `mypasswordis` and the number is not constant, can be 0, 1 or 2 or more. Or if the digit amount can vary in the number, or if there is any text after the number, etc. Otherwise, yes, a non-regex solutions are usually more straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE` instead to match what you *don't* want and delete that:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'^.*mypasswordis ', '')
```