# REGEXP_EXTRACT in Google BigQuery returns no results

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am using REGEXP_EXTRACT function in Google BigQuery to extract a specific word from a string. While regexp works good when tested, function REGEXP_EXTRACT returns null in Google BigQuery.

For example, there is string "RR_SM_Brand_A_Additive_Clean_jun2020", and I want to extract a value from the list (Brand_A, Brand_B, Brand_C, etc.)

When I test RegExp, I receive correct value Brand_A: https://regexr.com/5tecm

RegExp Code: `Brand_A|Brand_B` (thanks to @Barmar)

But when I run it in Google BigQuery:

`SELECT distinct utm_campaign,   -- REGEXP_EXTRACT(utm_campaign, r"(?:Brand_A|Brand_B)") REGEXP_EXTRACT(utm_campaign, r"Brand_A|Brand_B")  FROM project.dataset.table  WHERE utm_campaign = "RB_Display_Brand_A_Botanica_2020"`

I receive "This query returned no results.", and not expected Brand_A value.

Note: BigQuery does not return "Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?<"." like in question ["duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093941/bigquery-regex-to-match-number-of-8-digits-after-a-known-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that your WHERE clause may be at issue.  Both forms you use extract the brand string you appear to be asking for.  If the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` was not matching you'd still get rows, but the value would be NULL.

Converting this to just use the literal from your existing where clause:

```
SELECT 
  val,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(val, r"(?:Brand_A|Brand_B)"),
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(val, r"Brand_A|Brand_B")
FROM
(
    SELECT "RB_Display_Brand_A_Botanica_2020" as val
)
```

Comment: you are right! This query returned expected reults!